# Do not index all stores in multi-store prestashop 1.7

Tags: indexing, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, noindex

I have a multi-shop and I want one of the stores not to be indexed in any browser. What do I have to do to avoid indexing? The problem is that they share the robots. What I can do?
Can you do that a domain is not indexed in the robots? Being a multi-shop does not exist a folder to not index it, there is only the domain that points to the multitask of the prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 0):

you can edit header.tpl of your theme and do something like:

```
{if Context::getContext()->shop->id == ID_OF_STORE_YOU_DO_NOT_WANT_INDEX}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
{else}
<meta name="robots" content="{if isset($nobots)}no{/if}index,{if isset($nofollow) && $nofollow}no{/if}follow" />
{/if}
```

Comment: it's just checking for a shop id, if ID is equal to ID provided by you it will use noindex,nofollow to your meta robots tag

Comment: But this does not index all the pages that correspond to the domain of the store that I do not want to index?